# Why this tcmalloc error SbrkSysAllocator failed happen?

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, tcmalloc, google-perftools

I am using tcmalloc_minimal of google-perftools as the default memory allocater in my c++ program. It print out this infomation:

```
src/system-alloc.cc:427] SbrkSysAllocator failed
```

And the program goes on running. Does it matter?

Comment: Maybe you simply run out of memory? Also, according to this thread, version 1.7 doesn't show the message (but maybe it's just suppressed): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-perftools/whCzU9KRbwc

Answer (score 0):

By default tcmalloc takes memory from kernel using sbrk.
sbrk call may be failed in case of colliding memory mapping, and then tcmalloc fallbacks to pure mmap.
This is the moment when the message is generated.

There is nothing to worry about (as long as you do not run out of address space).